# Is there a way to schedule Heroku maintenance mode in advance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, maintenance-mode

We have an app running on heroku that we need to put into maintenance mode for an hour during the night while Amazon performs maintenance on the RDS instance we are using.

Does anyone know of a good way to schedule this?

I could create a cron job on one of the machines in the office to do it, but that seems a bit inelegant.

I'd rather do it from within the application itself, perhaps using `delayed_job` (which we are already using), or from a scheduled task. However I can't find any documentation about interacting with the Heroku management system from within a running application. Am I just not searching for the right thing?